# insert asp.net code behind property in html anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i have certain element in a asp.net control:

```
<a href="#" title="" style="background-image: url('../i/foo/image.png')">
```

but i want the background-image field being set from a control c# property

what are my options here?

basically i wanted to add something like:

```
<% if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BackgroundImageUrl)) {
    { %>
    <a href="#" title="" style="background-image: <%= item.BackgroundImageUrl%>">
<% } %>
```

but i'm not sure the `<%= item.BackgroundImageUrl%>` is correctly escaped inside the style property. What is the correct escaping pattern for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make HTML elements programmable, and accessible on the server side, add a `runat="server"`. Also, make sure the `<form>` tag has also `runat="server"`. Example:

```
<a href="#" id="some_id" runat="server" title="" style="background-image: url('../i/foo/image.png')">
```

On the server side do:

```
some_id.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
```

See this [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx) for more details

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching for this solution for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing..

```
<% if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BackgroundImageUrl)) {
    { %>
    <a href="#" title="">Text</a>
<% } %>
```

In  your styles sections..

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .selector { background-image:<%= item.BackgroundImageUrl %> }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<% if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BackgroundImageUrl)) { Response.Write("<a href=\"\" title=\"\" style=\"background-image: url('" + item.BackgroundImageUrl + "')\">"); } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem different answer. First of all mine was in a table so:

```
tr1 = New TableRow
thIn = New TableHeaderCell
thIn.CssClass = "Label"
Dim Anchor As New HtmlAnchor
Anchor.HRef = "PrintForm.aspx?iAuto=" & CStr(rsRCData("ID"))
Anchor.InnerHtml = "<img src='images/PrintButton.png' border='0' />"
Anchor.Target = "_blank"
thIn.Controls.Add(Anchor)
tr1.Cells.Add(thIn)
tbl1.Rows.Add(tr1)
```

Works for me.